# Antineutrino or anti-neutrino?

Tags: hyphenation

According to [this article](http://www.universetoday.com/51645/antineutrino/), one can write both. However, which form is the more commonly used? Which one should I use?

Comment: Ngram shows a wider use of "antineutrino". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anti-neutrino%2Cantineutrino&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canti%20-%20neutrino%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cantineutrino%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Layman here - *antineutrino* seemed a non-word; *anti-neutrino* was instantly comprehensible (albeit mystifying as well).

Comment: @Dan thanks for the feedback! I guess I'll use the one with the hyphen if I ever want to write for an audience which is not familiar with these terms so as to not confuse them.

Comment: @Skeleton Bow: I'd advise against the hyphen, on the grounds that 80% of writers (particularly, *scientists*, I'm sure) use the single-word forms. I've no idea why the people who typeset [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z8Dzuk-D9dsC&pg=PA40&dq=%22anti-matter%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22anti-matter%22&f=false) chose to use a hyphen in the title, where the text itself sticks to the more usual form. Whether it's *matter* or *neutrino* doesn't seem relevant to me.

Comment: That example you gave there is quite hilarious! I'll take your advice into account.

Comment: @Skeleton: I'm not actually a scientist. Although I'd like to *think* that they strive for consistency in their nomenclature, I've learned enough to know that reality doesn't always accord with my expectations. So I'll hang back from actually posting an answer, but I would just say that as a general principle we tend to discard hyphens over time rather than *add* them, so if you want your usage to still look reasonable in the future, go for the one-word form whenever it seems even close to a 50-50 split on *current* usage (but don't even *think* about, say, ***oneword***, obviously! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough! I'm not one either, just a student. Yes, I indeed remember reading an article about the abandonment of hyphens in modern English (pot belly instead of pot-belly, or even today instead of to-day!) as depicted by changes in a new version of the Oxford dictionary. I assume that's where we're headed. Once again, thanks for taking the time to post a useful comment!

Comment: The transition is usually *two words => hyphenated form => single word* (i.e. we don't get rid of the hyphen by changing it *back* to a space, we just run the two words together). Note that [***pot belly***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=potbelly%2Cpot+belly%2Cpot-belly&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpotbelly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpot%20belly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpot%20-%20belly%3B%2Cc0) is a slightly odd case (because it's still usually *a potbelly pig*, but *he has a pot belly*).

Comment: Consider your audience.  A non-scientific reader can read *anti-neutrino* and immediately make some sense of it (or at least pronounce it).  *Antineutrino* is (without having to stop and study it) unrecognizable and unpronounceable to the average reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ***[dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=antineutrino&ls=a)*** show the one word version "antineutrino" and also according to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anti-neutrino%2Cantineutrino&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canti%20-%20neutrino%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cantineutrino%3B%2Cc0)*** the single term version is the one more  commonly used.